# Как передать GET значение параметра в AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте. В адресной строке ссылка вида site.ru/folder/index.php?**id=1**
Нужно отправить AJAX запрос, в который нужно передать GET значение параметра **id**

Запрос выглядит так:

```
    .getJSON('/folder/ajax.php', {

        id: /*тут значение id*/

    }
```

Каким образом получить значение GET ?
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Где получить значение GET на каком языке вы пишите бекенд часть, ну как так можно? JAVA PHP NodeJS C# везде по разному єто происходит....

Comment: @Shnur извиняюсь, забыл уточнить. php

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так, если параметр `method` не будет отправлять GET то замените его на `type`

```
$.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/folder/ajax.php',
   data: {id: 1}
}).done(function(data){

});
```

php код

```
<?php

$id = empty($_GET['id']) ? '' : $_GET['id']
```

Comment: а почему `data: {id: 1}` ? id значение всегда разное будет в URL . и как мне значение GET параметра - id - подставить в мой запрос?

Comment: Вы просили пример, я дал вам пример, можете подставить туда переменную которая будет отправлять разные ID, ответ дан согласно сформулированному вопросу ) Сформулируйте более корректно вопрос чтобы получить на него нужный вам ответ )))